# Как снизить нагрузку на процессор?

Tags: mysql, сервер

Здравствуйте!

Есть сайт, у которого посещаемость в среднем 25к-30к в сутки. Недавно сменили сервер, на новом только памяти больше в два раза - оперативки хватает (64гб).
Ситуация такова, что в пиковые часы, процессор не выдерживает нагрузку, и начинает выдавать 500 или 502 ошибку, нагрузка в основном на процессор. Причем
ошибки бывают одна за одной.

На старом сервере количество процессов апача было сильно ограничено размером оперативной памяти, при увеличении количества процессов, они начинали падать
из-за нехватки памяти, но при этом ресурсов процессора и дисков хватало, чтобы во вменяемые сроки обслуживать процессы апача, а также mysql. Заменив сервер, мы увеличили количество процессов апача, они теперь могут поместится в памяти в большем количестве, но при этом эти процессы стали генерировать запросы к mysql в бОльшем количестве, чем до замены сервера, соразмерно увеличению количества самих процессов.

Раньше был сервер послабее
Intel® Core™ i7-4770 Quadcore Haswell
2 x 2048 GB HDD SATA-III
32 GB DDR3
,
перешли на мощнее

Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quadcore Skylake
HARD DRIVE
2 x 2048 GB HDD SATA-III
RAM
64 GB DDR4

Кто как решает вопрос снижения нагрузки на процессор? Буду благодарен любым предложениям как снизить нагрузку.

Comment: Вы можете уменьшить количество процессов Apache до такого количества, чтобы процессор выдерживал нагрузку. Это если нет времени, желания и времени оптимизировать код и запросы. Если есть, то заняться оптимизацией, в первую очередь уменьшая количество запросов к БД и оптимизируя сами запросы.

Comment: Уменьшение числа запросов, грамотная расстановка индексов, кэширование